# Convert Dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to perform a query in SQL Server. I'm having trouble filtering the date. The output is always the same, the data doesn't get filter by date.

The date comes in the following format:

```
29-12-2020 16:38
31-12-2020 17:43
```

I tried to filter doing all the following but none worked out:

```
select 
start_date 
from table_1
where start_date between '01-01-2021 00:00:00' and '31-01-2021 00:00:00'    

select 
start_date 
from table_1
where start_date between '01-01-2021 00:00' and '31-01-2021 00:00'

select 
start_date 
from table_1
where start_date between '01-01-2021' and '31-01-2021'
```

I also tried to cast it but I didn't have luck:

```
select
cast(start_date as date) as start_date 
from table_1
where start_date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'
```

Can anyone help me?
Regards

Comment: What is the data type of the start_date field in table_1?

Comment: Neither "none worked out" nor "I didn't have luck" are usable problem descriptions. What outputs/errors did you get exactly? Why were those wrong or insufficient?]

Comment: If you use an unambiguous literal value for your date literals, either `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` what happens?

Comment: The data did not get filtered

Comment: I would suggest, then, that your column is *not* a date (and time) data type. That's a severe design flaw you need to fix.

Comment: If your data is not stored as a date, and you can't fix that, then in your cast query, you need to cast as part of your where clause.  But that's a work-around, you need to store it as the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string.  I strongly suggest making it a date/time of some sort.  The following conversion works:

```
select convert(datetime, left(str, 10), 105) + convert(datetime, right(str, 5))
from (values ('29-12-2020 16:38')) v(str);
```

One operation is a computed column:

```
alter table table_1 start_date_dt as
    ( convert(datetime, left(start_date, 10), 105) + convert(datetime, right(start_date, 5)) )
```

Then you can use this value for your `where` clause.  Or better yet.  Fix the data!  Don't store values in strings when there is an appropriate data type.